# Identifying the index of an array inside a 2D array

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, python-3.8

I'm trying out an inventory system in python 3.8 using functions and numpy.
While I am new to numpy, I haven't found anything in the manuals for numpy for this problem.

My problem is this specifically:
I have a 2D array, in this case the unequipped inventory;
`unequippedinv = [[""], [""], [""], [""], ["Iron greaves", 15, 10, 10]]`

I have an if statement to ensure that the item selected is acceptable. I'm now trying to remove the entire index ["Iron greaves", 15, 10, 10] using `unequippedinv.pop(unequippedinv.index(item))` but I keep getting the error *ValueError: "'Iron greaves', 15, 10, 10" is not in list*

I've tried using numpy's where and argwhere but instead just got [] as the outcome.

Is there a way to search for an entire array in a 2D array, such as how SQL has `SELECT * IN y WHERE x IS b` but in which it gives me the index for the entire row?

Note: I have now found out that it is something to do with easygui's choicebox, which, I assume, turns the chosen array into a string which is why it creates an error.

Comment: I don't think what you're doing is good practice in general, however `unequippedinv.pop(unequippedinv.index(item))` where `item = ["Iron greaves", 15, 10, 10]` works fine for me.

Comment: Yeah, Ardweaden, it definitely works like that, so I think it's easygui.